# Checking if user already has account with PHP & ORACLE

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to apply the finishing touches on a register form. I want to check if the user already has an account, based on his e-mail address. However, the PHP won't help me out. Here is the main part of my code.

```
$s = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail='&mail'");
    oci_execute($s);
    $rows = 0;
    while (oci_fetch($s))
    {
        $rows ++ ;
    }
    echo $rows;  -> this echos all the time 0 even if I have 10+ registered users with same email
    if($rows > 0)
    {
       //has account
    }
    else{

       doesn't have account, inserting into DB
    }
```

It seems like the value of $rows is always 0, no matter what I Do. I also tried with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE mail='$mail'
```

But i was unable to pass the correct value to the $rows variable.

Everything else works fine in my php code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: in the first code you wrote : mail='&mail' but a variable will be written $mail like it is in your second code (sql statement) and if i remember correctly, you have to use .$mail. with dots to concatinate Strings with variables if you use "" insted of ''

Comment: That was silly from me. It's because of the & sign at the first select. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the sql statement you have written &mail insted of $mail.
And by the way to count your rows you can use the function `oci_num_rows($s)` with this function you dont have to use the while loop